# SingnalR on Windows 10: Connection blocked/pending after first message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr.client

I have a web app that uses SignalR over ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3.0 for async messaging and it works pretty well on IIS running on Windows Server.

However trying to run it on IIS running on Windows 10 Home, the web client (Chrome or Edge) gets stuck/blocked after receive the first message.

Looking to network tab on Chrome tools, it shows the web socket connection as "pending". And it never goes anywhere until I restart web site on IIS. When I do restart the web site then the client gets disconnected and can reconnect again.

Another scenario is when the client gets blocked/stuck with "pending" status, I close the browser and open it again. But then what happens is that ISS seems to be blocked and does not respond to any request, so I got to restart the web site on IIS.

The weird thing is that I have a development notebook with Windows 10 Home and the application work a charm on it. And I mean, it works running from Visual Studio debugging or direct from IIS Express started from terminal.

So botton line: I know it can work on Windows 10 Home, but the same problem I just related happened on 2 different notebooks running Windows 10 Home. Both machines are running up to date Windows, no pending update.

Any tips?

Comment: Do you have the right IIS version? If it's not an express, do you have WebSockets activated on it?

Comment: It is regular IIS 10, not the Express. Yes, web socket is activated -- as I said it works for the first message then it freezes. Pretty weird though.